# How to solve Unable to stop: Killed VM MobyLinuxVM did not stop error on docker

Tags: docker

I have installed Docker 17.12.0-ce on my windows machine and while running the docker I got following error how can I solve it?

```
Unable to stop: Killed VM MobyLinuxVM did not stop
at Fatal, <No file>: line 400
at Stop-VM-Force, <No file>: line 388
at Stop-MobyLinuxVM, <No file>: line 326
at <ScriptBlock>, <No file>: line 407
   at Docker.Backend.HyperV.RunScript(String action, Dictionary`2 parameters) in C:\gopath\src\github.com\docker\pinata\win\src\Docker.Backend\HyperV.cs:line 181
   at Docker.Backend.ContainerEngine.Linux.DoStop() in C:\gopath\src\github.com\docker\pinata\win\src\Docker.Backend\ContainerEngine\Linux.cs:line 306
   at Docker.Backend.ContainerEngine.Linux.Start(Settings settings, String daemonOptions) in C:\gopath\src\github.com\docker\pinata\win\src\Docker.Backend\ContainerEngine\Linux.cs:line 130
   at Docker.Core.Pipe.NamedPipeServer.<>c__DisplayClass9_0.<Register>b__0(Object[] parameters) in C:\gopath\src\github.com\docker\pinata\win\src\Docker.Core\pipe\NamedPipeServer.cs:line 47
   at Docker.Core.Pipe.NamedPipeServer.RunAction(String action, Object[] parameters) in C:\gopath\src\github.com\docker\pinata\win\src\Docker.Core\pipe\NamedPipeServer.cs:line 145
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Taken from [this github bug report](https://github.com/docker/for-win/issues/651) : apparently the Docker For Windows application must run as Administrator.